# x86 assembly, optimize conditional move

Tags: optimization, assembly, x86

This is threaded code command, like Forth `?`, check is `0` is on top of stack (`edi`) and skip next command by dereferencing command pointer (`ebx`).

```
_ifleap:
   mov eax, [edi]
   add edi, 4
   test eax, eax
   cmovz ebx, [ebx]
   mov ebx, [ebx]
   jmp [ebx + 12]
```

Is there a way to optimize this? Less lines, faster execution, better CPU support?
Idea is to check if `[edi]` is zero, then `mov ebx, [ebx]` otherwise do nothing. The `edi` must increment by 4 (this is sort of stack pointer). Of course `cmovz` is i686 only, but using label seems overkill for this task.

(Yes I have x86 instruction set reference, but it is huge, and takes long time to master, but I only use assembly occasionally, so I look for an expert advice.)

Comment: Typically it's `test eax, eax`; `cmp eax,eax` achieves nothing in this case, since that comparison always sets ZF. Also it can be better for some architectures to use `lea edi, [edi + 4]` in order of not to trash flags.

Comment: Can we see a bit more of the context? It's no use to optimize a line that is executed once or twice. What are the other constraints? Should we avoid memory accesses at all costs? What about the probability of eax==0?

Comment: Aki, I create programing language that uses threaded code, previously all threaded functions were C now I try to convert to ASM. This particular function is like Forth "?" instruction. If 0 is on top of stack skip next command. edi contains stack, ebx is pointer to current command.

Comment: This is about as far as you can take it with a TIL interpreter.  Going faster would require a jitter or dedicated hardware.  Chuck Moore is the TIL champion, [his processor](http://www.colorforth.com/S40.htm) looks moribund though.

Comment: You could try to exchange edi with esp; and when you need to actually jump to a subroutine, use `xchg edi, esp; call sub; xchg edi, esp`; This assumes that actual calls are rare and that push/pop convention, which is optimized for intel processors have better use in instruction level interpretation. Note that the order of cmov and mov do not matter.